# Disable specific W3C Logging Field

Tags: iis, logging, field, w3c

Is there a command or PS command to disable a specific W3C Logging Field?

I know you can just go to IIS manager and uncheck the box but I have a few hundred servers to do.

Comment: You may have more success with this question on Server Fault, which has many [questions about logging](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/logging).

Comment: thanks i will check it out